# Android Display Web View

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi I'm working on an android application that uses a web view. It works perfectly on most API levels, but I'm having problems on API 9 (Gingerbread 2.3.5). Where it's really inconsistent to whether it works or not. I've used the following code for it to work on froyo:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(urlString)) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
             handler.proceed();
        }
    });
```

but this doesn't get hit when debugging on API level 9 (Gingerbread 2.3.5). Has anyone else had this issue? if so what was causing it and how did you fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't an answer now, but a question of your idea. Did you try to start an activity or something like that if your site is loading or starting of the Webview ?

Comment: what do you mean by that sorry

Comment: like if you click to a .. youtube link android asks you to open the app, did ypu try something like this?

Comment: was I trying something while the webview was loading?

Comment: yes, like on loading check thr url for mine url or not and do somethnig?

Comment: all it does at the moment is just show two line of text on the html page, it will end up being a lot more but I just need to get the text displaying for now. Basically I have a link in the menu bar that takes the user to the web view activity. It just seem really temperamental where it works one day then the next just won't work, I was thinking it might just be taking a while to load, should I add anything in to it to say if it takes a certain length of time to load it produces an error message or something

Comment: You could create a new class which extends from webview client, there you already  has more methodes like on url load or something like that, there you could check how long it  tooks to load the site, and could bring a progress bar till the page  is loaded or after an timeout a error message, but i think it is a network problem, the network is too low and 2.3.5 isn't the newest android :D so it took so long because of the api

Comment: also you could get the progress state of loading the url by creating a new class extebds from webviewclient, there you could see what goes wrong